# use a bash variable as a java argument in bash script

Tags: java, bash

I have a bat and a bash script that compile and call a program with an argument that is the absolute path of a folder that is located in the same place as the scripts.

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

BDPATH= realpath ./BD
echo $BDPATH

javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main $BDPATH
```

script.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

set mypath=%cd%/BD

javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main %mypath%

pause
```

The second works as expected but the first one give me an error even if the "echo $BDPATH" shows me the right output, the error is this one:

```
/home/miu/bdd_projet-main/*REDACTED*/BD
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at bdd.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

It looks like the program acts like the was no arguments.

but if i replace the line

```
javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main $BDPATH
```

with

```
javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main test
```

It works.

Any ideas at how i could solve this ?

EDIT: managed to get "better" results doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main $(realpath ./BD)
```

i put

`set -xv`  as [markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366100/markp-fuso) told me to and i get this output:

```
javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/*.java && java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main $(realpath ./BD)
+ javac -d ./CODE/bin ./CODE/src/bdd/DBParams.java ./CODE/src/bdd/DiskManager.java ./CODE/src/bdd/Main.java ./CODE/src/bdd/PageId.java
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
++ realpath ./BD
+ java -cp ./CODE/bin/ bdd.Main /home/miu/bdd_projet-main/PROJET_BDDA_LI_LIN_HASNI_TIAN/BD
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
```

But i have another problem now, the program is after that supposed to create a file named f1.df which in this case will be in /home/miu/bdd_projet-main/*REDACTED*/BD
but instead it create DB/f1.df and is located in /home/miu/bdd_projet-main/*REDACTED*
Any idea why ?

Comment: in the `bash` script, before the `java` call, add `typeset -p BDPATH; set -xv`; `typeset -p` will show us the exact contents of the `BDPATH` variable while `set -xv` will show us what the `java` call looks like; run the script then update the question with these additional details

Comment: if this - `BDPATH= realpath ./BD` - is the actual line from the script, this is setting `BDPATH` to nothing

Comment: Please paste your `bash` script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Note that things passed to `javac` are not paased to the java program. Arguments passed to `java` are.